# How to make __set also work for static operation in PHP?

Tags: php, static, magic-methods

When I call `self::$parameter = 1;` the `__set` is not called.

Is there a way to workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):

> Property overloading only works in object context. These magic methods will not be triggered in static context. Therefore these methods should not be declared static. As of PHP 5.3.0, a warning is issued if one of the magic overloading methods is declared static.

So, I'm afraid not.

Comment: @user Let's say that I haven't come across a situation where I'd have needed this functionality, so I don't mind either way. It certainly *is* a missing feature though, and it's odd that there's a `__callStatic` function but no `__setStatic` function. It just goes to show once more that OO was an afterthought in PHP. Actually, modern PHP was an afterthought in PHP. ;)